# Indented Sass syntax not working with node-sass and gulp-sass

Tags: css, node.js, sass, gulp

Libsass 2.0 brought the indented syntax to libsass users, but so far I've been unable to make it work with `node-sass` and `gulp-sass`.  I have all of the latest versions:

**node-sass**: 0.93
**gulp-sass**: 0.7.2
**gulp**: 3.8.2

This setup compiles `.scss` files and even `.sass` files using the bracket syntax but it will not compile the indented syntax.  Has anyone successfully compiled the indented syntax with node-sass and gulp?

My `gulpfile.js`

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('./sites/all/themes/nsfvb/sass/screen.sass')
        .pipe(sass({
            includePaths: require('node-neat').includePaths,
            errLogToConsole: true
        }
        ))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./sites/all/themes/nsfvb/css'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('./sites/all/themes/nsfvb/sass/*.sass', ['sass']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'watch']);
```

**Error when running the default task**

`error: invalid top-level expression`

Comment: Your answer should be on: [https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-sass/issues/41](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-sass/issues/41). It's a known message.

Comment: I'm trying to figure this out too....

Comment: @Navelpluisje fyi, this isn't a syntax error, I've tested it with just one line of code.  It compiles with the curly braces and doesn't compile with the indented syntax.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Updated answer:

> If you want to use the indented syntax (.sass) as the top level file, use sass({indentedSyntax: true}).

```
sass({indentedSyntax: true})
```

### Outdated answer

Answer found here: https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass/issues/55#issuecomment-50882250

> With default settings compiling sass files doesn't work. However there is a workaround. If you pass sourceComments: 'normal' as parameter the compilation work. The reason for this is that there is a strange condition which change how file are handled: https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass/blob/master/index.js#L23-L27

Code example found here: https://github.com/chrisdl/gulp-libsass-example/blob/master/gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

// Run with "> gulp sass" in terminal.
gulp.task('sass', function () {
gulp.src('./sass/main.sass')
    .pipe(sass({sourceComments: 'normal'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});
```

### Notice

If you run into issues using this snippet take a look at the following quote and issue.

> Using this workaround will result in any changes to the file content from earlier in the gulp pipeline (e.g. earlier plugins) being discarded - JMM

https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass/issues/158

Comment: FYI, using that workaround will result in any changes to the file content from earlier in the gulp pipeline (e.g. earlier plugins) being discarded. See [dlmanning/gulp-sass#158](https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass/issues/158).

Comment: it works! but can be optimized. uselessly shows comments

Answer (score 1):

Just to update this answer, the [documentation for gulp-sass](https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass) now says:

> If you want to use the indented syntax (.sass) as the top level file, use `sass({indentedSyntax: true})`.