# How can i compiling sass files (gulp-sass)

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-sass, typesetting, gulp-ruby-sass

now i use Gulp-Ruby-Sass for Gulp.js

But the plugin gulp-ruby-sass slower than gulp-sass.
I am very comfortable to typeset through .sass files.

Are there ways to typeset through gulp-sass + .sass files?

P.S. Sorry for my English.

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24397679/indented-sass-syntax-not-working-with-node-sass-and-gulp-sass/25211459#25211459

Answer (score 0):

I found a way, how do it with gulp-sass

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
gulp.src('src/sass/index.sass')
    .pipe(sass({indentedSyntax: true}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/css'))
    });
```